# Unable to fetch data in collection from kinvey to a table view controller

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, kinvey

Hi i have a collection in kinvey with two columns Team1 & Team2. Now i need to fetch this data and assign it to Label1 & label2 in the Table view controller. I have implemented a model class to fetch the data. Here is my Model Class Code.

```
class FixtureData:NSObject{

var Team1:NSString!
var Team2: NSString!
var entityId: NSString?

init(Team1:String, Team2:String) {
    self.Team1 = Team1
    self.Team2 = Team2
    print(Team1)

}
override var description:String {
    return "Team1: \(Team1!)"
}
override init(){
    super.init()
}
```

Below is the code. I have taken it from Kinvey to map the columns in Kinvey to my code.

```
        override func hostToKinveyPropertyMapping() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!
```

{
    return [
        "entityId" : KCSEntityKeyId, //the required _id field
        "Team1" : "Team1",
        "Team2" : "Team2",}

> The problem here is if i put a break point at Team1 & Team2 and check i am not getting any data from kinvey.

My table view controller has this code

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FixtureCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    var team1Lbl : UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UILabel
    let team2Lbl : UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UILabel
    let fc = FixtureData()
    fc.hostToKinveyPropertyMapping()
    team1Lbl.text = Team1[indexPath.row]
    team2Lbl.text = Team2[indexPath.row]}
```

So here please some one let me know what should i modify in the code, to fetch the data.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see KCSAppdataStore implementation in your code. KCSAppdataStore is the base class for data that allows you to send and load data from the backend.

Check following link in detail for better understanding of the implementation :

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/datastore#KCSAppdataStore

Thanks,
Pranav